# Triangulation of a surface

Tags: geometric-topology, triangulation

In their [2015 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5805) on random simplicial complexes, Costa and Farber
casually mention without a proof that in triangulation of a closed surface, there is a formula
$$\frac{\text{number of $1$-faces}}{\text{number of $2$-faces}} = \frac{3}{2}.
$$ I was wondering if this is a well-known result and whether the following statements are true.

1. in a triangulation of a surface, every $1$-simplex is contained in at most two $2$-simplexes.
2. in a triangulation of a closed surface, every $1$-simplex is contained in exactly $2$-simplexes.

The former statement would imply the latter, but I don't know how to go on about proving (or disproving) the first statement.

Comment: If a $1$-simplex is contained in, say, three $2$-simplices, then can you find some neighborhood of a point on your $1$-simplex that is not a manifold?

Comment: Yes, this is quite well known: For a closed surface, each face is a triangle, so contributes 3 edges. But if we multiply 3 by the number f of faces to get the total number e of edges, then each edge is counted exactly twice because of statement 2. above. Thus e = (3/2)f.

Answer (score 0):

In a 2-dimensional simplicial complex $X$, for every 1-simplex $E$, and for every point $p$ in the interior of $E$, the local homology $H_2(X,X-p)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^{k-1}$ where $k$ equals the number of 2-simplices that contain $E$.

But if $X$ is also a manifold then $H_2(X,X-p)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ for all $p \in X$.

So every $1$-simplex is contained in exactly $k=2$ 2-simplices.